# create temp file using utils in java not using : java.io.File.createTempFile()

Tags: java, file, io, java-io, fileutils

Currently I am using `java.io.File.createTempFile()` to create a temp file. But it has a validation to filter out those file names which is less than 3 words. Like this

```
if (prefix.length() < 3)
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Prefix string too short");
```

But I want to consider those cases where the length of title can be 1. So can anyone suggest a good alternate or any commons api to be able to do create temp file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this should do what you want :

```
    File f = new File(FileUtils.getTempDirectoryPath() + filename);
```

Comment: That looks good but in File.createTempFile it does other validation as well like security validation please refer [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/File.java#File.createTempFile%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.io.File%29).
So I would like to find more of a util api instead of implementing it.
As they say why invent a new wheel if there is already one.